# Ordenamiento de Array en PHP

Tags: php, mysql, array, base-de-datos, backend

Buen día comunidad, tengo una duda de cómo ordenar un arreglo que obtengo en base a la consulta a mi base de datos, el resultado que obtengo es este.

```
    [
    {"title":"Empleado","subtitle":"Listado","dir":"ver_empleados.php","icon":"fas fa-file-alt"},
    {"title":"Empleado","subtitle":"Alta Candidatos","dir":"dar_alta.php","icon":"fas fa-user-plus"},
    {"title":"Empleado","subtitle":"Citar","dir":"citar.php","icon":"fas fa-user-plus"},
    {"title":"Empleado","subtitle":"Entrevistar","dir":"entrevista.php","icon":"fas fa-user-plus"},
    {"title":"Empleado","subtitle":"Examen","dir":"examen.php","icon":"fas fa-user-plus"},
    {"title":"Empleado","subtitle":"Documentos","dir":"documentos.php","icon":"fas fa-user-plus"},
    {"title":"Empleado","subtitle":"Contratar","dir":"contratar.php","icon":"fas fa-user-plus"},
    {"title":"Nomina","subtitle":"Ver","dir":"ver.php","icon":""},
    {"title":"Nomina","subtitle":"Reestablecer","dir":"update.php","icon":""},
    {"title":"Nomina","subtitle":"Eliminar","dir":"delete.php","icon":""}
]
```

Pero lo quiero ordenar de esta manera.

```
[
[
    {"title":"Empleado","subtitle":"Listado","dir":"ver_empleados.php","icon":"fas fa-file-alt"},
    {"title":"Empleado","subtitle":"Alta Candidatos","dir":"dar_alta.php","icon":"fas fa-user-plus"},
    {"title":"Empleado","subtitle":"Citar","dir":"citar.php","icon":"fas fa-user-plus"},
    {"title":"Empleado","subtitle":"Entrevistar","dir":"entrevista.php","icon":"fas fa-user-plus"},
    {"title":"Empleado","subtitle":"Examen","dir":"examen.php","icon":"fas fa-user-plus"},
    {"title":"Empleado","subtitle":"Documentos","dir":"documentos.php","icon":"fas fa-user-plus"},
    {"title":"Empleado","subtitle":"Contratar","dir":"contratar.php","icon":"fas fa-user-plus"}
],
[
    {"title":"Nomina","subtitle":"Ver","dir":"ver.php","icon":""},
    {"title":"Nomina","subtitle":"Reestablecer","dir":"update.php","icon":""},
    {"title":"Nomina","subtitle":"Eliminar","dir":"delete.php","icon":""}
]
```

]

Esto desde el lenguaje PHP, hay alguna forma de ordenarlo ??

Comment: Eso mas que un orden, pareceria ser como que queres obtener 2 arreglos?

Comment: Sería del primer arreglo separar los que tengan el titulo de Nomina para poder agregarlos en un nivel del arreglo aparte, no sé si me explico

Comment: o sea lo unico que queres hacer es obtener 2 arreglos en lugar de uno, como tenes ahora? separando por titulo? cual seria la finalidad?

Comment: Así es, crear un menú dinámico en base al segundo arreglo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Autor: https://github.com/jakezatecky/array_group_by

```
<?php
function array_group_by(array $arr, $key) : array
{
    if (!is_string($key) && !is_int($key) && !is_float($key) && !is_callable($key)) {
        trigger_error('array_group_by(): The key should be a string, an integer, a float, or a function', E_USER_ERROR);
    }
    $isFunction = !is_string($key) && is_callable($key);
    // Load the new array, splitting by the target key
    $grouped = [];
    foreach ($arr as $value) {
        $groupKey = null;
        if ($isFunction) {
            $groupKey = $key($value);
        } else if (is_object($value)) {
            $groupKey = $value->{$key};
        } else {
            $groupKey = $value[$key];
        }
        $grouped[$groupKey][] = $value;
    }
    // Recursively build a nested grouping if more parameters are supplied
    // Each grouped array value is grouped according to the next sequential key
    if (func_num_args() > 2) {
        $args = func_get_args();
        foreach ($grouped as $groupKey => $value) {
            $params = array_merge([$value], array_slice($args, 2, func_num_args()));
            $grouped[$groupKey] = call_user_func_array('array_group_by', $params);
        }
    }
    return $grouped;
}
```

Tendrias lo siguiente:

```
$records = [
    ["title" => "Empleado", "subtitle" => "Listado", "dir" => "ver_empleados.php", "icon" => "fas fa-file-alt"],
    ["title" => "Empleado", "subtitle" => "Alta Candidatos", "dir" => "dar_alta.php", "icon" => "fas fa-user-plus"],
    ["title" => "Empleado", "subtitle" => "Citar", "dir" => "citar.php", "icon" => "fas fa-user-plus"],
    ["title" => "Empleado", "subtitle" => "Entrevistar", "dir" => "entrevista.php", "icon" => "fas fa-user-plus"],
    ["title" => "Empleado", "subtitle" => "Examen", "dir" => "examen.php", "icon" => "fas fa-user-plus"],
    ["title" => "Empleado", "subtitle" => "Documentos", "dir" => "documentos.php", "icon" => "fas fa-user-plus"],
    ["title" => "Empleado", "subtitle" => "Contratar", "dir" => "contratar.php", "icon" => "fas fa-user-plus"],
    ["title" => "Nomina", "subtitle" => "Ver", "dir" => "ver.php", "icon" => ""],
    ["title" => "Nomina", "subtitle" => "Reestablecer", "dir" => "update.php", "icon" => ""],
    ["title" => "Nomina", "subtitle" => "Eliminar", "dir" => "delete.php", "icon" => ""]
];



$grouped = array_group_by($records, 'title');

echo json_encode($grouped);
```

Que te dara como resultado:

```
{
  Empleado: [
    { title: 'Empleado', subtitle: 'Listado', dir: 'ver_empleados.php', icon: 'fas fa-file-alt' },
    {
      title: 'Empleado',
      subtitle: 'Alta Candidatos',
      dir: 'dar_alta.php',
      icon: 'fas fa-user-plus',
    },
    { title: 'Empleado', subtitle: 'Citar', dir: 'citar.php', icon: 'fas fa-user-plus' },
    { title: 'Empleado', subtitle: 'Entrevistar', dir: 'entrevista.php', icon: 'fas fa-user-plus' },
    { title: 'Empleado', subtitle: 'Examen', dir: 'examen.php', icon: 'fas fa-user-plus' },
    { title: 'Empleado', subtitle: 'Documentos', dir: 'documentos.php', icon: 'fas fa-user-plus' },
    { title: 'Empleado', subtitle: 'Contratar', dir: 'contratar.php', icon: 'fas fa-user-plus' },
  ],
  Nomina: [
    { title: 'Nomina', subtitle: 'Ver', dir: 'ver.php', icon: '' },
    { title: 'Nomina', subtitle: 'Reestablecer', dir: 'update.php', icon: '' },
    { title: 'Nomina', subtitle: 'Eliminar', dir: 'delete.php', icon: '' },
  ],
}
```

Comment: Excelente. me ha servido bastante, muchas gracias.

Comment: @gbianchi puedes revisar y cualquer critica seria de ayuda. :)

Comment: Mucho mejor ;).. ahora es otra cosa.. fijate como la proxima persona con un problema similar, no va a tener que ir de un lado para otro ;)